# Entity Framework 4: Generic return type for a method

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have the following code -

```
    var db = new DBEntities();
    var entity = //get entity;

    lblName.Text = string.Empty;
    var names = entity.Names.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i < names .Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == names .Count - 1) lblName.Text += names [i].Value + ".";
        else lblName.Text += names [i].Value + ",&nbsp;";
    }
```

I'll have several For loops like above which will format the value to be displayed in a label. I'm trying to make a method out of it which will do the formatting when I pass in the collection and the label, something like -

```
void FormatValue(List<??> items, Label label)
    {
        //For loop
        //Format value
    }
```

What do I pass in for the List. How do I make this generic enough so I'll be able to use it for all `entity.Names`, `entity.Xxx`, `entity.Yyy` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the method itself generic and allow the caller to specify a formatter:

```
void FormatValue<T>(List<T> items, Label label, Func<string, T> formatter)
{
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        label.Text += formatter(item);
    }
}
```

You can then call the method like:

```
FormatValue<Name>(entity.Names.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList(),
                  lblName,
                  i => i.Value + ", &nbsp;");
```

Comment: void FormatValue<T>(IList<T> items, Label label)
        {
            label.Text = string.Empty;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == items.Count - 1) label.Text += items[i].?? + ".";
                else label.Text += items[i].??+ ",&nbsp;";
            }
        } How do I access a property of the collection? When I do items[i].Value, it throws an error saying "Identifier expected.

Comment: Thank you. The For/Foreach has two parts to it - one will add a period at the end if it's the last item or will add a comma. Where do I write that in your sample? Thanks!

Comment: @user349308 - There are several ways you could approach it. You could change the foreach to a for loop and then allow the caller to pass a lastItemFormatter in addition to the regular formatter or you could try to add something to the Func to handle the different formats as well.